# Program runs too slowly with large input - C

Tags: c, arrays, string

The goal for this program is for it to count the number of instances that two consecutive letters are identical and print this number for every test case. The input can be up to 1,000,000 characters long (thus the size of the char array to hold the input). The website which has the coding challenge on it, however, states that the program times out at a 2s run-time. My question is, how can this program be optimized to process the data faster? Does the issue stem from the large char array?

Also: I get a compiler warning "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" for the line `str[1000000] = ""` What does this mean and how should it be handled instead?

**Input:**
number of test cases
strings of capital A's and B's

**Output:**
Number of duplicate letters next to each other for each test case, each on a new line.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, c, a, results[10] = {};
    char str[1000000];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        str[1000000] = "";
        scanf("%s", str);
        for (a = 0; a < (strlen(str)-1); a++) {
            if (str[a] == str[a+1]) { results[c] += 1; }
        }
    }
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        printf("%d\n", results[c]);    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to terminate with a nul character, not a string: `str[1000000] = '\0';` And that's the 10000001th element of your array, so you need to declare str one longer. As for the efficiency, try computing the strlen into a variable and use that in the loop bound, just to be sure it isn't being recalculated every time.

Comment: Instead of using `strlen` in `for` loop condition , calculate it before and store in variable and then test against that variable .

Comment: Why are you messing with an array at all?  If you track dupes as you read then you only ever need to know what were the previous two characters read.  `stdin` does its own buffering.

Comment: If you're only interested in two consecutive letters you only need to store one letter – the last one you read. And you don't need to store the results for each test case, just print them immediately.

Comment: Don't call `strlen(str)` each time through the loop. That makes your loop `O(n^2)`, because `strlen()` has to search for the null character every time (although some compilers are smart enough to optimize this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the line

```
str[1000000] = "";
```

`scanf()` adds a null terminator when it parses the input and writes it to `str`. This line is also writing beyond the end of the array, since the last element of the array is `str[999999]`.

The reason you're getting the warning is because the type of `str[10000000]` is `char`, but the type of a string literal is `char*`.

To speed up the program, take the call to `strlen()` out of the loop.

```
size_t len = strlen(str)-1;
for (a = 0; a < len; a++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note: `str[0] = 0;` is prudent as code does not check the result of `scanf()`.  Yet best to check its result.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The online compiler yelled at me for changing the type to of str to char*. What makes char* so different in the first place? The fact that it points to the location in memory as opposed to being the variable itself? Also, taking out the string length test worked like a charm. I believe this knowledge will help me a good bit in the future when it comes to optimization (not just with strlen calls).

Comment: @JoeyGrant  A string is an array of characters. `str` is a string, and so is `""`. `str[1000000]` is one character in that string. If you change it to `char *str[1000000]`, that's an array of pointers, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
str[1000000] = "";
```

This does not do what you think it does and you're overflowing the buffer which results in `undefined behaviour`. An indexer's range is from 0 - sizeof(str) EXCLUSIVE. So you either add one to the 
1000000 when initializing or use 999999 to access it instead. To get rid of the compiler warning and produce cleaner code use:

```
str[1000000] = '\0';
```

Or

```
str[999999] = '\0';
```

Depending on what you did to fix it.

As to optimizing, you should look at the assembly and go from there.

Comment: `scanf()` doesn't require the buffer to be null terminated, it will add the null terminator itself.

Comment: @Barmar Detail : `scanf("%s", str)` only adds the null character when some non-white-space was saved (likely) and a rare input error did not occur.  So insuring `str[0] = '\0';` is initialized is not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

> count the number of instances that two consecutive letters are identical and print this number for every test case

For efficiency, code needs a new approach as suggeted by [@john bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger)  & [@molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875786/program-runs-too-slowly-with-large-input-c#comment55515348_33875786)

```
void ReportPairs(const char *str, size_t n) {
  int previous = EOF;
  unsigned long repeat = 0;
  for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int ch = (unsigned char) str[i];
    if (isalpha(ch) && ch == previous) {       
      repeat++;
    }
    previous = ch; 
  }
  printf("Pair count %lu\n", repeat);
} 

char *testcase1 = "test1122a33";
ReportPairs(testcase1, strlen(testcase1));
```

---

or directly from input and "each test case, each on a new line."

```
int ReportPairs2(FILE *inf) {
  int previous = EOF;
  unsigned long repeat = 0;
  int ch;
  for ((ch = fgetc(inf)) != '\n') {
    if (ch == EOF) return ch;
    if (isalpha(ch) && ch == previous) {       
      repeat++;
    }
    previous = ch; 
  }
  printf("Pair count %lu\n", repeat);
  return ch;
} 

while (ReportPairs2(stdin) != EOF);
```

Unclear how OP wants to count "AAAA" as 2 or 3.  This code counts it as 3.

Answer (score 0):

One way to dramatically improve the run-time for your code is to limit the number of times you read from `stdin`. (basically process input in bigger chunks). You can do this a number of way, but probably one of the most efficient would be with `fread`. Even reading in *8-byte* chunks can provide a big improvement over reading a character at a time. One example of such an implementation considering capital letters `[A-Z]` only would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RSIZE 8

int main (void) {

    char qword[RSIZE] = {0};
    char last = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t nchr = 0;
    size_t dcount = 0;

    /* read up to 8-bytes at a time */
    while ((nchr = fread (qword, sizeof *qword, RSIZE, stdin)))
    {   /* compare each byte to byte before */
        for (i = 1; i < nchr && qword[i] && qword[i] != '\n'; i++)
        {   /* if not [A-Z] continue, else compare */
            if (qword[i-1] < 'A' || qword[i-1] > 'Z') continue;
            if (i == 1 && last == qword[i-1]) dcount++;
            if (qword[i-1] == qword[i]) dcount++;
        }
        last = qword[i-1];  /* save last for comparison w/next */
    }

    printf ("\n sequential duplicated characters [A-Z] : %zu\n\n",
            dcount);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output/Time with 868789 chars**

```
$ time ./bin/find_dup_digits <dat/d434839c-d-input-d4340a6.txt

 sequential duplicated characters [A-Z] : 434893


real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.005s
```

**Note:** the string was actually a string of `'0's` and `'1's` run with a modified test of `if (qword[i-1] < '0' || qword[i-1] > '9') continue;` rather than the test for `[A-Z]...continue`, but your results with `'A's` and `'B's` should be virtually identical. 1000000 would still be significantly under .1 seconds. You can play with the `RSIZE` value to see if there is any benefit to reading a larger (suggested 'power of 2') size of characters. (*note:* this counts `AAAA` as `3`) Hope this helps.